# convenient collection of class variables

Tags: python

Python beginner here. I am trying to write a convenience function to access class variables from a list of objects.

currently, I am writing one function for each variable. For example, I have a class 'swarm' that contains 'animals'. Each animal has many variables that store time series such as position, heading etc. (Only a couple are given in the example below.)

I am looking for a convenient way to access a specific variable from all animals from the Swarm class. I want to obtain a matrix with n columns where n is the number of animals.

```
import numpy as np

class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=np.zeros(10)
        self.y=np.ones(10)

class Swarm(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.animals=[]
        self.animals.append(Animal())
        self.animals.append(Animal())

    def get_all_x(self):
        x1=self.animals[0].x
        x2=self.animals[1].x
        return np.stack([x1,x2],axis=-1)

s=Swarm()
s.get_all_x()
```

in pseudo code, I would like a function in the 'Swarm' class that takes the variable name to be collected as a string input. something like this:

```
def get_var_from_all(self,var):
   return np.stack([x.var for x in self.animals],axis=-1)
```

obviously, this way of accessing 'var' doesn't work. any hints?

Comment: Use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getattr(obj, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) -- it's a built-in function that tries to retrieve the field or method with the given `name` from the provided `obj`, if that attribute exists.

```
def get_var_from_all(self, var):
   return np.stack([getattr(x, var) for x in self.animals],axis=-1)
```

(You may also be interested in [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) if you plan on doing more metaprogramming.)

Comment: great! Can this be extended to cases where in the example above, x would again be an object with variables a and b for example? In that case, I would like something like getattr(pair, 'x.a') but this doesn't seem supported

Comment: @jlarsch -- you would probably need to chain multiple `getattr`s together to make that work -- for example, do`getattr(getattr(pair, 'x'), 'a')` or write a loop if you want to make the logic more general-purpose..

Comment: I ended up using this: `       var=['x','a']
        for i in range(len(var)):
            tmp=[getattr(x, var[i]) for x in tmp]
        return np.stack(tmp,axis=-1)`